# Could not copy the file ADS.mdf" because it was not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, mdf

I am new to programming. Currently, I am working on a project. When I am trying to build the project, its giving me the following errors. Any help/ suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File Line Error Could not copy the file "C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\Aquas\SITAS\Code_Cloned\Code\Code_Rekha
>   di\Code\Code\WSSC-ADS Sewer Inspection\ADS.mdf" because it was not
>   found.    WSSC-ADS Sewer Inspection
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error      Could not copy the
>   file "C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\Aquas\SITAS\Code_Cloned\Code\Code_Rekha
>   di\Code\Code\WSSC-ADS Sewer Inspection\ADS_log.ldf" because it was not
>   found.    WSSC-ADS Sewer Inspection

Comment: This is not a programming question, nor is there even a question in there.  This belongs in StackExchange.

Comment: Which I understand you're using tools made for programming, this is the sort of problem that could occur with any sort of application, not just a coding related one, so I'm recommending it be moved to Super User.

Comment: If you go to that path do the files ADS.mdf and ADS_Log.ldf exist?